# SQL - Grouping duplicates and unique id issue

Tags: sql, duplicates, grouping

hope someone can point me in the right direction.  I'm having a bit of a hair pulling moment.

Here is some sample data:

```
ID    SUBID   COL1      COL2      COL2      COL3
1     10001   Test 1    Test 2    Test 3    Test 4
2     10002   Test 1    Test 2    Test 3    Test 4
3     10003   Test 1    Test 2    Test 3    Test 4
4     10004   Test 1    Test 2    Test 3    Test 4
5     10005   Test 5    Test 6    Test 7    Test 8
```

I need the result to look like this:

```
ID    SUBID   COL1      COL2      COL2      COL3
4     10004   Test 1    Test 2    Test 3    Test 4
5     10005   Test 5    Test 6    Test 7    Test 8
```

I need to group all duplicates based on COL1, COL2, COL3 & COL4 which is easy but I need to output a number from the groupings in the ID and SUBID column, it doesn't matter which of the grouped rows this comes from, it just needs a value.

Performance is also key in doing this as I'm querying millions of rows.

Hope the above makes sense and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could choose one by using min or max. They won't be from the same row, but it is "just a value".

```
select min(id), min(subid), col1, col2, col3, col4
from tab
group by col1, col2, col3, col4
```

Comment: I'm sure I tried this earlier and it didn't work!!  Works now, thank you so much Stefan.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, subid, COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
from your_table
where id in (
             select min(id)
             from your_table
             group by COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
            )
```